# AppleScript To Manipulate VLC

Tags: macos, applescript, script, error, vlc

I want to do a script, that it can launch VLC player, and in VLC player "Open a file", then 
"Select a folder", then click on "add" then "play" it. I think that Automator can't do this. But Applescript seems legit, right?

How to build an easy script, that I can save as an application then setup it to the startup folder?

Path : the folder in question `/Users/server_raagc/Copy`

(I tried automator, then applescript, then terminal with a .plist then another automator combined with an applescript saved as application, all of this in a different way times 36.

My code :

```
set workflowpath to "/Users/server_raagc/Desktop/FINAAAAAL - copie.workflow" 
set qtdworkflowpath to quoted form of (POSIX path of workflowpath) 
set command to "/usr/bin/automator " & qtdworkflowpath 
set output to do shell script command
```

Always an error. Or here trying to code another one. Same thing.

```
 activate application "VLC"
 tell application "System Events"
keystroke "O" using command down
 end tell
 tell application "System Events" to tell process "VLC"
click button "Parcourir..." of window 1 of window 2
 end tell
```

The automator Test:
Maybe becauce one is an "Watch Me do"?

[image: image desc]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This AppleScript will open the specified folder in VLC and begin to play the contents:

```
tell application "VLC"
  OpenURL "file:///Users/grgarside/Desktop/test/"
  play
end tell
```

Comment: It's a great restart, but here the thing is i want to VLC to play a foler, when i do 

`tell application "VLC" OpenURL "/Users/ruedifly/Desktop/SaintvPatrick/
Play 
end tell` 





Doesn't work for me, 'cause it's folder
How can i do that ?

Comment: For me on Snow Leopard running VLC 2.0.7 I had to add a second `play` to get it to start... Maybe my settings are messed up but the above solution works.

Answer (score 2):

open folder then run script

```
tell application "Finder" to set cwd to POSIX path of (insertion location as alias)

tell application "VLC"
    OpenURL "file://" & cwd & ""
    play
end tell
```